# Split data (from text/json file) based on platform (Using Python)

Tags: python, json, split

This is sample data ( JSON file)
 - JSON file filled in with exactly the same line, as this "JSON" file is ready to be uploaded to Big Query, looking for the way of splitting it by platform.

```
{"origin": {"detailed": "instagram", "source": "instagram", "platform": "instagram"}.....}
{"origin": {"detailed": "website", "source": "website", "platform": "website"}.....}
{"origin": {"detailed": "forum", "source": "forum", "platform": "forum"}.....}
{"origin": {"detailed": "twitter", "source": "twitter", "platform": "twitter"}.....}
{"origin": {"detailed": "facebook", "source": "facebook", "platform": "facebook"}.....}
```

I'm looking for splitting this data into different text files based on platform.

```
if platform = instagram ( but some how it should be - if line contain "platform": "instagram" )
    write to post_instagram.json
if platform = facebook
    write to post_facebook.json
..............
    ...................
```

What is the clean way to do it? - BY using PYTHON

**Sample:**

```
with open(FILE_NAME, "r") as infile:
    Data = infileFollow.read()
    If statements?
    while statement?
    .....

with open(FILE_NAME, "w+") as outfile:
    outfile.write(Data)
```

**Reason:**
I'm looking to spit the data as could not create the single schema which will accept different platforms, as different platforms have extra repeated columns which break consistency, even if I create the schema with all columns for all platforms. So as solution need to split data based on platforms so that it will be a different schema for each.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
import json 

json.dump([x for x in data if "instagram" in x["origin"]["platform"]], open("post_instagram.json", "w"))

json.dump([x for x in data if "facebook" in x["origin"]["platform"]], open("post_facebook.json", "w"))

# other platforms ...
```

If data is very huge instead of iterating all data for each "platform":

```
instagram = []
facebook = []

for d in data:
    if "instagram" in d["origin"]["platform"]:
        instagram.append(d)
    elif "facebook" in d["origin"]["platform"]:
        facebook.append(d)

json.dump(instagram, open("post_instagram.json", "w"))
json.dump(facebook, open("post_facebook.json", "w"))
```

Comment: That is a really good solution, my file is not pure JSON, as it modified to be ready to upload to Big Query it do not contain commas at the end of each line, so it Big Query JSON file ))) .... Sorry for not full explanation... I'm looking for exactly the save but based on (IF line containt /// "platform": "twitter" //// write this line to post_twitter, because all my tries to used python/json method, do not work - I will modify code to make it more clear.

Comment: have update the question (JSON SAMPLE), please have a look

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the json module for python.

Then you can `json.load` your file and get a dictionary as output, and then iterate over `your_dict['origin']['platform']` to write the line in a file named `'post_'+platform+'.json'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON module.

**Ex:**

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

with open(filename) as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)     #Read JSON


res = defaultdict(list)
for i in data["data"]:
    res[i["origin"]["platform"]].append(i)

for k,v in res.items():
    with open("post_{}.json".format(k), "w") as outfile:   #Open Required file for Write.
        json.dump(v, outfile)
```

Sample Json in this Example.

```
{
    "data": [
        {"origin": {"detailed": "instagram", "source": "instagram", "platform": "instagram"}},
        {"origin": {"detailed": "website", "source": "website", "platform": "website"}},
        {"origin": {"detailed": "forum", "source": "forum", "platform": "forum"}},
        {"origin": {"detailed": "twitter", "source": "twitter", "platform": "twitter"}},
        {"origin": {"detailed": "facebook", "source": "facebook", "platform": "facebook"}}
    ]
}
```

Comment: your code will overwrite the output file every time in the loop, so you will only get the last line

Comment: You are right. I did not see that. Thanks.  Updated ans.