# Split text file (line by line) to different files

Tags: python, text, split

Looking for data splitter line by line, by using python

- RegEx?
- Contain?

As example file "file" contain:

```
X
X
Y
Z
Z
Z
```

I need the clean way to split this file into 3 different ones, based on letter

**As a sample:**

```
def split_by_platform(FILE_NAME):

    with open(FILE_NAME, "r+") as infile:
        Data = infile.read()
        If the file contains "X"
            write to x.txt
        If the file contains "Y"
            write to y.txt
        If the file contains "Z"
            write to z.txt
```

**x.txt** file will look like:

```
X
X
```

**y.txt** file will look like:

```
Y
```

**z.txt** file will look like:

```
Z
Z
Z
```

Comment: Read the file and count the occurrences of each unique element, then simply create new files for each unique element and write them accordingly.

Comment: What about iterating over the lines using `str.starswith()` in a conditional statement?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111917/split-data-from-text-json-file-based-on-platform-using-python

Comment: @NANA why did you post a new question then ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers because that question should be constructed differently, as this is not JSON question, this is text file modification by using python.

Comment: yes I found out reading comments in the other question.

Comment: So you only have X, Y and Z letters or you can have the whole alphabet or any kind of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT thanks to @bruno desthuilliers, who reminded me of the correct way to go here:

Iterate over the file object (not 'readlines'):

```
def split_by_platform(FILE_NAME, out1, out2, out3):

    with open(FILE_NAME, "r") as infile, open(out1, 'a') as of1, open(out2, 'a') as of2, open(out3, 'a') as of3:
        for line in infile:
            if "X" in line:
                of1.write(line)
            elif "Y" in line:
                of2.write(line)
            elif "Z" in line:
                of3.write(line)
```

EDIT on a hint of @dim:
Here the more general approach for an arbitrary length list of flag chars:

```
def loop(infilename, flag_chars):
    with open(infilename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            for c in flag_chars:
                if c in line:
                    with open(c+'.txt', 'a') as outfile:
                        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Why use `readlines()` here ? It loads the whole file in memory for no good reason, when you can just iterate directly over the file (` for line in infile: ...`).

Comment: Completely correct, my mistake. Thanks for correcting this.

Comment: @SpghttCd, this will be a good approach if you only have letters X, Y and Z, but what happens if you have the whole alphabet?

Comment: Well, I know that your answer adresses this question very well. But first it was not requested by OP, and second it leads to opening and closing the target files over and over again, so it has it's drawback, too. However, asap I can add the 'n-char'-version, if it's interesting.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
with open('my_text_file.txt') as infile, open('x.txt', 'w') as x, open('y.txt', 'w') as y, open('z.txt', 'w') as z:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith('X'):
            x.write(line)
        elif line.startswith('Y'):
            y.write(line)
        elif line.startswith('Z'):
            z.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more generic way to do the same job:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("file.txt", "r+") as file:
    data = file.read().splitlines()
    counter = Counter(data)
    array2d = [[key, ] * value for key, value in counter.items()]
    print array2d # [['Y'], ['X', 'X'], ['Z', 'Z', 'Z']]
    for el in array2d:
        with open(str(el[0]) + ".txt", "w") as f:
            [f.write(e + "\n") for e in el]
```

The above code will generate `X.txt`, `Y.txt` and `Z.txt` with the corresponding values. If you have for example several `C` letters the code will generate a file `C.txt`.

Comment: Just a hint (btw for anybody here, including myself, as every answer shows this mistake): use the file open mode 'a' instead of 'w' to not to overwrite all the lines until the last... :)